# How to cite with superscript (and use et al.) in usepackage{scicite}

Tags: citing, superscripts

I tried to fix this myself but i`m not so very much LaTex experienced yet and i cant figure it out.

I use `documentclass{Article} and userpackage{scicite}`
So for citatations and library i
I`m using  scicity.sty, here the link http://www.sciencemag.org/sites/default/files/scicite.sty
For making of the .bib  i use Mendelay (if relevant)

I am guessing that in scicite there is a code that i can use to supercite and i need to copy to my .latex ? I tried to copy several parts but i am not really understanding the guidelines and nothing worked. The answers i found on this site in regards to superscript also havent worked, because i havent managed to exchange 
I tried these two for example (and many many others):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cite}{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@tempswatrue\@citex}{\@tempswafalse\@citex[]}}

\def\@citepc#1{%
   \ifx\@tempb#1\@empty #1\let\@tempc\oc@movep \fi
   \ifx\delimiter#1\else \expandafter\@citepc\fi}
```

But i either get an error code that something of this is not defined or falsely defined or my citation is simply still not correct. 
It is shown like :

- This protein is expressed in mitosis( *3*).

But what i want it to be  a superscripted number 1 or as [1] , as usually it is done in science papers.

I tried to replace `\usepackage{scicite}` by

```
\usepackage[]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
    \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}%
    \bibopenbracket}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {\bibclosebracket}
```

But any attempt ( i tried other codes too) to replace scicite with biblatex results in the following error code : .bll not created

ALSO i have a library generated by mendelay using et. al (and it shows this correctly), when i import it however to latex it will not use et al. when there re more than 3 authors.
I`m using

```
\bibliography{scibib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
```

minimal code (i hope im doing this right):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scicite}
\usepackage{arial}

\pretolerance=10000
\tolerance=2000 
\emergencystretch=10pt
\makeatletter
\let\latexl@section\l@section
\def\l@section#1#2{
\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\latexl@section{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\topmargin 0.0cm
\oddsidemargin 0.2cm
\textwidth 17cm 
\textheight 23cm
\footskip 1.0cm

\newenvironment{sciabstract}{%
\begin{quote} \bf}
{\end{quote}}
\title{ }
\author{•}


\begin{document} 
\baselineskip18pt
\maketitle \newpage
\tableofcontents

\bibliography{scibib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code a minimal complete code example.

Comment: Have you tried loading the `scicite` package with the option `superscript` (or `super` for short)?

Comment: can you please define what "loading" means? How do i load a package  with a option? I never done that before.

Comment: i tried to write and\usepackage{scicite}{<super>}  i get an error code ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}, same when i go with superscript

Comment: i tried \usepackage{scicite}[superscript], which loaded a pdf without error but supercite is still not defined and cite doesnt result in supercitation either.